# Incorrect response while testing with maven, while JUnit returns correct response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I have an IAM application which runs the spring-authorization-server (version 0.4.0) on spring-boot 2.7.x and I wanted to migrate to spring-authorization-server 1.0.1 and spring-boot 3.0.2. The migration process went fairly smooth and all the tests pass as expected, using intelliJ.

However, after pushing it to the repo I see that using maven test, not all test pass. This is reproducible locally, and after investing a lot of time into it, I still don't get why it is not working.

When I do a GET request to the oauth endpoint (with the cookie), I get a 200 response, while if I run it with IntelliJ I get a 302 (with the correct code in the location header).

When I run the application and do the requests manually, it also does as expected.

The filterchain is set up like this:

```
http
            .securityMatcher(authorizationEndpointMatcher)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(authorizationEndpointMatcher))
            .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
                new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint(customDomainRepo, identityProviderRepo, serverProperties.getScheme(),
                    clientProperties.getWebClientRedirects(), urlUtil, serverProperties));
```

When I spring security in trace mode I get this response with intelliJ:

```
HTTP GET http://localhost:60914/oauth/authorize?audience=test&scope=user&response_type=code&client_id=webclient&redirect_uri=http://app-local.com:8080/?oauth&state=secretState&device=JavaIntegrationTestCode&code_challenge=7ZccZOoyQsIK3xJw9ZAfJg4S530kJ4EQS-HfL_ywiUU&code_challenge_method=S256
12:13:23.755 | DEBUG | o.s.w.client.RestTemplate | Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
12:13:23.761 |  INFO | o.a.t.u.h.parser.Cookie | A cookie header was received [Expires=Sun, 26 Mar 2023 11:13:23 GMT;] that contained an invalid cookie. That cookie will be ignored.
 Note: further occurrences of this error will be logged at DEBUG level.
12:13:23.762 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Or [Mvc [pattern='/v1/me/**'], Mvc [pattern='/v1/admin/iam/**'], Mvc [pattern='/v1/devices/**']], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@596c189f, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2d6645a4, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@d0e05e8, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@32101098, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@5aef1a93, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@51145fdc, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@3282806f, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@c624fdc, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3ec40a18, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7cc87859, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@22360505, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@649cae23, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@519cb1bd]] (1/3)
12:13:23.766 | TRACE | o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping | Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]] and 4 interceptors
12:13:23.767 | TRACE | o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping | Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]] and 4 interceptors
12:13:23.768 | TRACE | o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping | Mapped to HandlerExecutionChain with [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]] and 4 interceptors
12:13:23.768 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$2251/0x0000000801a278e8@5a3e14bf, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@ffbdb79, org.springframework.security.web.session.ForceEagerSessionCreationFilter@67ea360f, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3c9a8c66, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@56d8cf3a, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerContextFilter@1722bd4e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@244285a9, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@16abeca6, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7462f6a0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@778324fd, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter@3c1ddea3, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter@7bd44868, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.NimbusJwkSetEndpointFilter@4262a8d2, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter@1403187e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@a98ce67, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@574dcc6a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@475add19, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@444379eb, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5fd6cf33, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@2fd250ed, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenEndpointFilter@4080bcd9, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenIntrospectionEndpointFilter@6d0c8cd0, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.web.OAuth2TokenRevocationEndpointFilter@3adb51f2]] (2/3)
12:13:23.768 | DEBUG | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Securing GET /oauth/authorize?audience=test&scope=user&response_type=code&client_id=webclient&redirect_uri=http://app-local.com:8080/?oauth&state=secretState&device=JavaIntegrationTestCode&code_challenge=7ZccZOoyQsIK3xJw9ZAfJg4S530kJ4EQS-HfL_ywiUU&code_challenge_method=S256
12:13:23.768 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/22)
12:13:23.768 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking ForceEagerSessionCreationFilter (2/22)
12:13:23.773 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (3/22)
12:13:23.773 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (4/22)
12:13:23.773 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking AuthorizationServerContextFilter (5/22)
12:13:23.774 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (6/22)
12:13:23.774 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking CorsFilter (7/22)
12:13:23.774 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking CsrfFilter (8/22)
12:13:23.777 | TRACE | o.s.s.web.csrf.CsrfFilter | Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match And [CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS], Not [Or [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.annotation.web.configurers.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer$$Lambda$2251/0x0000000801a278e8@5a3e14bf]]]
12:13:23.778 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking LogoutFilter (9/22)
12:13:23.778 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.a.l.LogoutFilter | Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
12:13:23.778 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationServerMetadataEndpointFilter (10/22)
12:13:23.778 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy | Invoking OAuth2AuthorizationEndpointFilter (11/22)
12:13:23.781 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository | Retrieved SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=CustomUserPrincipal(accountId=01daff67-d0fb-4a0f-a2b6-995b26335b1d), Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]] from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
12:13:23.784 | TRACE | o.s.s.a.ProviderManager | Authenticating request with OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider (1/11)
12:13:23.784 | TRACE | o.s.s.o.s.a.a.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider | Retrieved registered client
12:13:23.785 | TRACE | o.s.s.o.s.a.a.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider | Validated authorization code request parameters
12:13:23.795 | TRACE | o.s.s.o.s.a.a.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider | Generated authorization code
12:13:23.838 | TRACE | o.s.s.o.s.a.a.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider | Saved authorization
12:13:23.838 | TRACE | o.s.s.o.s.a.a.OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider | Authenticated authorization code request
12:13:23.839 | DEBUG | o.s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy | Redirecting to http://app-local.com:8080/?oauth&code=Vrf6WVMF4j-QLC7YpEAfq6n-M_OGf-KEgVFviqJa6OxNXTei8-qpNcZ4aUE-F8fxzXJWxp8rVFu4P7-nQkw5L_GL13So1WTnvs17N6sFr-9KMpUcJsk_8zbiSbc7BhBz&state=secretState
12:13:23.840 | TRACE | o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter | Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
12:13:23.850 | DEBUG | o.s.w.client.RestTemplate | Response 302 FOUND
```

But when I run it with maven I get this:

```
 HTTP GET http://localhost:60953/oauth/authorize?audience=test&scope=user&response_type=code&client_id=webclient&redirect_uri=http://app-local.com:8080/?oauth&state=secretSt
ate&device=JavaIntegrationTestCode&code_challenge=ydCfzpu7z45snP7JU8Q1cAoHv9_47txZgknJyarC-6E&code_challenge_method=S256
12:15:21.245 | DEBUG | o.s.w.client.RestTemplate | Accept=[text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
12:15:21.251 |  INFO | o.a.t.u.h.parser.Cookie | A cookie header was received [Expires=Sun, 26 Mar 2023 11:15:21 GMT;] that contained an invalid cookie. That cookie will be ignored.
 Note: further occurrences of this error will be logged at DEBUG level.
12:15:21.258 | DEBUG | o.s.w.client.RestTemplate | Response 200 OK
```

Some extra info, I have setup this TestRestTemplate override, to prevent the redirect. Which changed because spring boot 3 uses httpClient5 instead of 4.

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestRestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory());
    }

    private ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
            .disableRedirectHandling()
            .disableCookieManagement()
            .build();
        factory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

At first I assumed this had to do with the issue mentioned here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.1.0-M1-Release-Notes#dependency-management-for-apache-httpclient-4

But I updated to milestone 1 of spring boot 3.1.0, but that also doesn't fix it.

Does anybody have any clue what could cause this? Or has some tips on how to debug this further, because I have tried everything I can think of.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

After attaching a debugger to the maven test, I see that it fails in this part: [see line of source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/FilterChainProxy.java#L194).

With the error: `The request was rejected because the HTTP method "SES" was not included within the list of allowed HTTP methods [HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, PUT]`. So it looks like something is going wrong with making creating the method that it is sending. However, I'm unsure why.

Comment: Have you tried [adding a test dependency](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#apache-httpclient-in-resttemplate) of `org.apache.httpcomponents.client5:httpclient5`? It seems that you are using the desired `HttpClient` but I thought it worth mentioning, since I believe no longer following redirects is a side effect of upgrading to Spring Boot 3.

Comment: Yes I added:
```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```
And any reference to the old httplclient. However, I'm not sure if it has to do with the httpClient. As you can see in the trace logs. The response gets handled completely different, depending on if it is a maven or an intelliJ run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed by updating to spring boot 3.1.0. I don't know what the issue was exactly, but probably some conflict somewhere with the new apache httpclient 5.